# How do i use TLBIMP.EXE?

Tags: c#, .net, import, components, tlbimp

I've found it in my visual studio folder, but when i open it it simply loads and closes instantly. is that the right way to reach to it's functionalities ?

Comment: you should have a look at [Type Library Importer (Tlbimp.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: The exe needs arguments on which library needs to be imported. Open visual studio command prompt & type "tlbimp" to see what argument it expects.